# echo output special characters issue

Tags: csh

I'm not sure what the issue is here,

```
set rreq = '"\"select[OS=RHEL]\""'
echo $rreq
echo: No match.
```

trying to get output of rreq as "select[OS=RHEL]"

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add quotes around the variable name to prevent shell globbing on the `[..]`:

```
set rreq = '"\"select[OS=RHEL]\""'
echo "$rreq"
```

Which gives:

```
"\"select[OS=RHEL]\""
```

In most shells, a variable is treated much more similar to a macro expansion than to special syntax, so `echo $rreq` is the same as if you had typed `echo "\"select[OS=RHEL]\""`.

I think you want to drop those extra quotes and backslashes though:

```
set rreq = '"select[OS=RHEL]"'
```